# How to successfully assign a variable from within a block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I'm using this custom method to parse HTML using a WKWebView:

```
- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavascript:(NSString *)javascript
{
    NSString *string = @"";

    [self.webView evaluateJavaScript:javascript
               completionHandler:^(id result, NSError *error){

                   if (error) {

                       NSLog(@"Javascript:%@\nError: %@", javascript, error.description);
                   }
                   else {

                       NSString *parsedString = (NSString *)result;

                       NSLog(@"Parsed String: %@", parsedString);

                       __block string = parsedString;
                   }
               }];

    return string;
}
```

Which I'm using like this:

```
NSString *count = [self stringByEvaluatingJavascript:@"document.getElementsByTagName('a').length"];

NSLog(@"Count: %@", count);
```

It logs:

```
Count:

Parsed String: 242
```

While I'm getting this warning:

> Incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'int' with an
>   expression of type 'NSString *__strong'

How to successfully assign the content of **parsedString** ("242") to **string** from within the block?

Comment: You need to type cast `NSString` to `Int`. I'm not sure how in Obj-C though...

Answer (score 1):

The method that you described in this question should not return any value because the `string` variable will be initialized in `completionHandler` of `evaluateJavaScript`. You should use this method:

```
- (void)stringByEvaluatingJavascript:(NSString *)javascript
                   completionHandler:(void(^)(NSString*))completionHandlerForEvaluateJS {
    [self.webView evaluateJavaScript:javascript
                   completionHandler:^(id result, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Javascript:%@\nError: %@", javascript, error.description);
            completionHandlerForEvaluateJS(nil);
        } else {
            NSString *parsedString = (NSString *)result;
            NSLog(@"Parsed String: %@", parsedString);
            completionHandlerForEvaluateJS(parsedString);
        }
    }];
}
```

How to call it:

```
[self stringByEvaluatingJavascript:@"document.getElementsByTagName('a').length" completionHandler:^(NSString *count) {
    NSLog(@"Count: %@", count);
}];
```

And about this error:

> Incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'int' with an
>   expression of type 'NSString *__strong'

You get it because `__block string` is a short form for `int __block string`.

Comment: I'd suggesting passing `nil` to the completion handler if there is an error since an empty string might be a valid result.

Comment: @rmaddy It is a very good idea, but as I understood `stringByEvaluatingJavascript` should never return `nil`.

Comment: Exactly. That's why you should use `completionHandlerForEvaluateJS(nil);` inside `if (error) {`. This way the caller knows there was an error and not just an empty result.